# Why do I get a nomethod error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I call this method in my controller:

```
delete_heard_timeline_event(current_user.id, @showable_video.user.id, @showable_video.video.id)
```

and I definite it in my model:

```
  def delete_heard_timeline_event(actor_id, subject_id, secondary_subject_id)
      TimelineEvent.find_by_actor_id_and_subject_id_and_secondary_subject_id_and_event_type(actor_id, subject_id, secondary_subject_id, 'heard_event').destroy
  end
```

Why is rails telling me that the method is undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined this method as `instance` method so you need to to call it like this:

```
a = YourModelName.new
a.delete_heard_timeline_event(your_parameters)
```

and if this methods is `class` method so call:

```
YourModelName.delete_heard_timeline_event(your_parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see there is already accepted answer, but to answer to your question:

if this NoMethodError pops out because of this line:

```
find_by_actor_id_and_subject_id_and_secondary_subject_id_and_event_type
```

I think Rails can handle max 3 conditions and you have 4 there.

And because you are in Rails 3, you could do it like this:

```
class TimelineEvent
  def self.delete_heard_event(actor_id, subject_id, sec_id)
    self.scoped.where(:actor_id => actor_id,
     :subject_id => subject_id,
     :secondary_subject_id => sec_id,
     :event_type => 'heard_event').first.try(:destroy)
  end
end
```

The .try method at the end tries to fire a method in it's parameter, but only on non-nil objects, so you are safe to call it with wrong parameters.

Then just:

```
TimelineEvent.delete_heard_event(current_user.id, @showable_video.user.id, @showable_video.video.id)
```

Regards, NoICE

Comment: also how do you know Rails can handle a max of 3 conditions? it wasn't what was throwing the error

Comment: `scoped` creates ActiveRelation instance for this object (well..in this example it wasn't needed, because .where does the same :), but I like to write it. About those 3 conditions - I thought I saw it in ActiveRecord code which defines find_by_* attribute... But I can be wrong. What was causing the error, then?